# How to configutre Guzzle3 to use a handler other than cURL?

Tags: php, sockets, curl, guzzle

Due to a cURL bug I need to configure Guzzle3 to use a handler other than cURL for the request. In the docs it says it's possible but doesn't say how:

> Guzzle can use any HTTP handler to send requests. This means that Guzzle can be used with cURL, PHP's stream wrapper, sockets, and non-blocking libraries like React. You just need to configure an HTTP handler to use a different method of sending requests.

How can I tell Guzzle to use sockets/stream wrapper or anything other handler except cURL?